# Updated the selected view in list view webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, jsom

Good morning, I have awired issue to reflect the changes in list view to list view webpart in web part page programmatically using JSOM

What exactly I need to change the selected view in list view web part to a specific view using JavaScript JSOM, Is it possible?

If it's not possible, how can I delete the list viewer web part from the web part page after that add it again to the same webpart zone using JSOM?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure we have an option to change the different Views in ListView Webpart using JSOM.

But yes there are option to delete and and the webpart again using JSOM. here is refrernce 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185010(v=office.14)

Below is code for adding the webaprt, XML you can get by exporting your webpart.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection/Default.aspx';

function addWebPart() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);

    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);

    var webPartXml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' + 
        '<WebPart xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"' + 
        ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"' + 
        ' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2\">' + 
        '<Title>My Web Part</Title><FrameType>Default</FrameType>' + 
        '<Description>Use for formatted text, tables, and images.</Description>' + 
        '<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><ZoneID></ZoneID><PartOrder>0</PartOrder>' + 
        '<FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>' + 
        '<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>' + 
        '<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>' + 
        '<AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink />' + 
        '<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall />' + 
        '<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>' + 
        '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter />' + 
        '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ' + 
        'PublicKeyToken=94de0004b6e3fcc5</Assembly>' + 
        '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
        '<ContentLink xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" />' + 
        '<Content xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + 
        '<![CDATA[This is a first paragraph!<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>And this is a second paragraph.]]></Content>' + 
        '<PartStorage xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" /></WebPart>';

    var oWebPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.importWebPart(webPartXml);
    this.oWebPart = oWebPartDefinition.get_webPart();

    limitedWebPartManager.addWebPart(oWebPart, 'Left', 1);

    clientContext.load(oWebPart);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Web Part added: ' + oWebPart.get_title());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

For deleting the Webpart

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection/SitePages/Home.aspx';

function retrieveWebParts() {

    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(server2RelativeUrl);

    this.limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    this.collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

    clientContext.load(collWebPart);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.deleteWebPart), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

    function deleteWebPart () {

        if (!collWebPart.get_count()) {
            alert('No Web Parts to delete.');
        }

        var webPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts().get_item(0);

        webPartDefinition.deleteWebPart();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {

        alert('Web Part deleted.');
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

I think little bit more research will solve your problem

Comment: That's great, how can I get the xml format for my list view web part

Comment: You can add first List view webpart then open the Context menu of Webpart and click on Export.It will be downloaded as wsp and then you can open in notepad XML will be present. follow below link upto 4 steps only there.https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/exporting-and-importing-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2013