# The getLimitedWebPartManager is not a function

Tags: 2016, jsom

In the context of my previous questions:

- [Updated the selected view in list view webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247393/updated-the-selected-view-in-list-view-webpart/247413#247413)
- [how can I get the xml format for my list view web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247709/how-can-i-get-the-xml-format-for-my-list-view-web-part)

I encountered an error when running this line:

```
var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
```

The following error message is shown:

> The getLimitedWebPartManager is not a function

Any thoughts on what may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing SSOM API (server-side object model through C# for example) and JSOM API (JavaScript object model).

Using JavaScript, there is no GetLimitedWebPartManager() function, as the error message clearly states.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245876.aspx), you should use:

```
var object = new SP.WebParts.LimitedWebPartManager()
```